# VSCode: Disable mouse+ctrl interaction

Tags: visual-studio-code

I often double-click to select followed by ctrl+c to copy. I am finding in vscode that ctrl press with the mouse over a word can perform an action. In some cases it selects the whole line, and in others it jumps to the definition of what is underneath. Is there a way to turn this off?

Note that if you move the mouse cursor off the word then it appears the action is not performed.

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is old, but this is the first thread that appears in search.

A solution to this: "I am finding in vscode that ctrl press with the mouse over a word can perform an action."
is to go into Selection menu > and then choose "Switch to Ctrl+Click for Multi-Cursor"

(for some it might work the other way around "Switch to Alt+Click for Multi-Cursor" - because on my computer i have remapped/switched left ALT and left CTRL places - old mac habit to have cmd closer to the spacebar)

... hope this helps someone.

Answer (score -1):

You could click on Visual Studio code->Preferences->KeyBoard Shortcuts.  Keyboard Shortcuts page opens up.  You could change any of the keyboard short cuts, by click on edit icon on the left as shown below

[image]

Comment: I don't think this list contains the shortcut OP is talking about.

Comment: yeah - I looked there but didn't see anything related to the mouse which is a key component here...if you find the specific related setting i'm happy to try it.

Answer (score -3):

You can change the behavior of these features or disable them altogether by going to Tools > Options > Text Editor.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/productivity-structure-visualizer-ctrl-click-to-go-to-definition/